# Local Notification alternative week repeat

Tags: iphone, ios, localnotification

I Have two notification and I want to repeat it alternative week.

E.g. One notification set on 1st week's monday and it should repeat on 3rd week's monday.
     Second notification set on 2nd week's tuesday and it should repeat on 4th week's tuesday.

What should I do for this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit*2;

Comment: Try adding 14 days to the current day , that might get you to the alternate week day of your current date..

Comment: I tried it but what about after 14 days.

Comment: Need this repeat continue after 14 days like 1st,3rd,5th,7th and so on.....

Comment: @Chirag, add the code you tried to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Get week number 
and make decision according to week number

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*) getWeekOfMonth {
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
 [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"W"];

 NSString *weekNumber = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];    
 [dateFormatter release];    
 return weekNumber;
}

NSInteger weekInt = [weekNumber integerValue];
```