# Setting the repeat interval after a fire date in unnotificationrequest

Tags: ios, swift

I have previously used `UILocalNotification` and there was a property to set a repeat interval but I am not getting any option to set that in `UNNotificationRequest`.

I want the notification to be fire at a specific date and after that, it should repeat every minute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391494/ios-10-repeating-notifications-every-x-minutes ?

Comment: You can set a UNNotificationRequest to the specific date, once it triggered you can use UILocalNotification to repeat it every minute.

Comment: I want the notification to be fire at a specific date and then repeat every minute.

Suppose it fires at tomorrow 4:30 pm and after that, it should fire every minute. i.e 4:31, 4:32.. etc